# How does Chromium store cookie (expiration) time?

Tags: cookies, chromium

If you manually open the cookies SQLite3 database for FireFox cookies, the time is stored as `unixepoch`.

An example cookie (taken only the `host` and `expiry` columns):

```
outlook.office.com|1612178984
```

If I get the cookies from the SQLite3 database from Chromium (or any Chromium-based browser, like Brave) the time format isn't `unixepoch` and I can't figure out what it is, maybe it's somehow encrypted?

An example (again, only taking the `host_key` and `expires_utc` columns):

```
brave.com|13258124587568466
```

Comment: For what operating system? Cookies are encrypted by Chromium but not sure if it's encrypted on all the platforms

Comment: I'm using Linux, or more specifically Linux Mint 20 (based on Ubuntu 20).